# Socket.IO, SSL Problems With cloudflare

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, cloudflare, spawn

I'm having a socket.io app that basically receives signals from a frontend in order to kill and start a new ffmpeg process (based on .spawn()).

Everything works like expected, but often I get a 525 error from cloudflare. The error message is: Cloudflare is unable to establish an SSL connection to the origin server.

It works like 9 out of 10 times.I noticed that more of these errors pop up whenever a kill + spawn is done. Could it be the case that something block the event loop and because of this blocks all incoming requests and cloudflare logs these as a handshake failed error?

Contacting cloudflare support gives me back this info (this is the request they do to my server):

```
    Time    id      host    message     upstream  
2017-08-16T09:14:24.000Z    38f34880faf04433    xxxxxx.com:2096 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream   https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2096/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LtgKens
```

I'm debugging for some time now, but can't seem to find a solutions myself.

This is how I initialize my socketIO server.

```
/**
     * Start the socket server
     */
    var startSocketIO = function() {
        var ssl_options = {
            key: fs.readFileSync(sslConfig.keyFile, 'utf8'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(sslConfig.certificateFile, 'utf8')
        };

        self.app = require('https').createServer(ssl_options, express);

        self.io = require('socket.io')(self.app);

        self.io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'polling']);

        self.app.listen(2096, function() {
            console.log('Socket.IO Started on port 2096');
        });
    };
```

This is the listener code on the server side

```
this.io.on('connection', function (socket) {

        console.log('new connection');

        /**
         * Connection to the room
         */
        socket.on('changeVideo', function (data) {                            
            //Send to start.js and start.js will kill the ffmpeg process and 

start a new one
                socket.emit('changeVideo');
            });
   });
```

Another thing that I observer while debugging (I only got this a few times):

The text new connection displayed on the server and the connected client emits the changevideo event but nothing happens on the server side instead the client just 
keeps reconnecting.

This is a simplified version of the nodejs code. If you have more questions, just let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your Node app isn't crashing (and being restarted)?

Comment: I'm running the server manually on the command line and I'm 100% sure that the process isn't crashed.